# Why using RESTFul web service to populate a database is a good habit?

Tags: android, mysql, rest, database-connection

My question actually is in the title.
I am developing an Android application which populates a distant mysql database (in an amazon cloud server).

Why not using the same techniques used in java programs (like using a import java.sql.Connection object)?

Thank you, R.

Comment: timeout, async, connection, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092230/181766

Comment: Thanks JJchinw, That's sounds a logical answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Tons of benefits in REST , few are below

You can use standard HTTP method call-outs, available on every language and platform, to make requests and retrieve information

Standards-based security: Utilize the OAuth protocol for authenticating your REST calls

Flexible formats: The REST API supports both an XML serialization as well as the JSON format

Comment: IMO, this answer is misleading, "HTTP cache and proxy server..." why does this help me when I'm populating stuff? http cache is not going to cache my data that I want to populate... "your complex business/database logic..." and again why does this help me in this situation..."you don't need to make separate..." there is a url to post/put what you want to insert in the db....

Comment: "last but not the least, json is too light than xml" where in the rest spec say that you must use json, I can use xml if I want to, there are many rest services that use xml too. And in all the answer it does not answer, "Why not using the same techniques used in java programs (like using a import java.sql.Connection object)?"