# How to connect an android app to a remote database?

Tags: android, database, listview, connection

I've been doing my own research but to no avail. I am doing an android app which contains listviews and it needs to query data from a remote database. I would really appreciate it if someone could share good tutorial links that teach that kind of stuff. Sorry, I know this isn't a proper question but I really need some help. Thanks.

Comment: You really don't want to communicate with the database directly, primarily for security reasons. Ideally, you'll want to set up a web service to communicate with the DB and and serve data from it to your app. See this tutorial:http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up a connection with remote database in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092095/how-to-set-up-a-connection-with-remote-database-in-android)

Answer (score 10):

You can refer to this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Or refer to this [image: diagram]

Answer (score 3):

How about a simple web service in the middle?

It helps to prevent you putting database username/pw directly in the app too.

App -> Http requests -> Web service -> Database

The Http requests can be done via Android [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)

The web service can be in [php for example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database). (There is a lot example for php to database on google.)

Answer (score 3):

To communicate with the remote databse, you require web service which can fetch data from or suit data to remote database.

I am not sure about which web platforms are you using currently but I would suggest you to go with REST with JSON.

Comment: @TiaraZarin which web technology are you using? PHP, .NET or any other?

Comment: I plan to use ASP .net.

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical case of `SyncAdapter` with it you can use the remote database from your content provider as a regular DB.

I have done it and it works well with only few complexities.