# How can I create an Android booking system which is linked to a PC based server program?

Tags: java, android, database, distributed-system, portable-applications

To make it as simple as possible I am creating a booking system for a hotel. I need an application which will be an Android app and a Java program which will act as a server sending out data as requested. My my main priority is getting my app and the program to work together.

I have experience in Java so the Java side is fine. The only thing I am concerned about is how to get the app and the program to be able to access the same database and retrieve or change details etc.

Does anybody have any idea of where I need to start this? I have 2 months so I'm in the research stage right now.

Comment: This type of broad, research question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. We aim to answer specific programming problems with specific answers. I've voted to close this as "too broad". See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for more info.

Comment: This is irrelevant to stack overflow..u can choose some other sites...

Comment: @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj Please make *much more* substantive edits in future. Had I seen [that edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3945752) myself, I would have rejected it "too minor".

Comment: @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj for your information [I have now edited what I consider to be minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21480591/revisions). Perhaps have a look at it for future edits.

Comment: @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj Thanks for spell/grammar checking for me shows you have a lot of time on your hands. Wish I could say the same! user1736258 I think your post was the only helpful one everyone else seemed to be more concerned how its too "broad". Cause its broad I was in the design stage not knowing how im going to solve the issue yet. That's what programming is about. So when someone asks you to create a system but doesn't give enough detail and their too "broad" then lets see if you keep your job..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use WebService and JSON. I leave a link to another contribution which gives a tutorial. I think that's what you're looking for.

[How to connect an android app to a remote database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704672/how-to-connect-an-android-app-to-a-remote-database)