# Best way to connect an android app to a remote database?

Tags: android

I am doing an android app which needs to interact with a remote database. I am hesitating since three weeks between two ways to perform this task. Either create a REST service,  or call a PHP script which handles communication between my app and Database. I look at some good stuff on this topic like 
[How to connect an android app to a remote database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704672/how-to-connect-an-android-app-to-a-remote-database)
It helps nevertheless I am still reluctant to choose between them. So I would really appreciate if someone could share good tutorial links or tell me some strengths and weakness of either (security of database, complexity, best architecture,...) to be sure I do the best choice. Actually my Database is MySql

Thank you.

Comment: The advantage of using a php is that all maintenance be done in php (server-side), for me this is the best way (was not I who became negative your question)

Comment: You should elaborate on your requirements, quantitatively at least.

Comment: What does orientation of architecture depends on volume of requirements? Can you clarify more please?

Comment: I carefully read it as I put it into my description but sorry I didn't know the best candidate between using Rest or only php. Now I understand that it is possible to use rest with php. What I didn't understand before. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I make all the sharing beetwin android and server side... it's with PHP on server side... in especific with yii framework... I send the data via http post... and Yii do the rest...for example To make a Login activity I just need 4 lines of code in the server side...
 you can always post what you had done so we can help you on it... 
if more help is needed I'll be more than happy to help you...

Comment: sorry for the english...

Comment: Hi, So you combine Yii and Rest? Indeed i am about to implement my needs. It's first why before going head down, i am looking for some feedback on that. Thank you