# Encountering java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver in Android

Tags: android, mysql

On android I'm attempting a connection to a MySQL database hosted in Google Cloud SQL which I've connected and performed create, read, update and delete actions essentially using the same code whilst developing in Java Swing.I've made slight adjustments for use in Android e.g. adding log messages.

In my connection manager class specifically in the method openConnection() I'm encountering the following error:

> 01-14 12:36:25.891: I/UsersLogInDataConnMgr(3769): openConnection() -
>   Connection faliure: - java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Having gone through similar posts I made sure I avoided the following errors which seem to be associated with the error issue I'm encountering:

- Making sure the MySQL Connector/J is in my build path. I can confirm
  this as I can see it listed in referenced libraries.
- Ensuring my URL is correctly formatted.

In addition I attempted the adding the code below before executing Driver.getConnection() in my openconnection() method:

```
    try {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This led to the following error:

> 01-14 13:12:14.445: W/System.err(4180): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Below is my **UsersLogInDataConnMgr** class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.util.Log;

public class UsersLogInDataConnMgr {

    private static UsersLogInDataConnMgr instance = null;
    private static final String USERNAME = "uname";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "pwrd";
    private static final String M_CONN_STRING =
            "jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:3306/testdb";
    private DBType dbType = DBType.MYSQL;
    private Connection conn = null;
    private String TAG = "UsersLogInDataConnMgr";

    private UsersLogInDataConnMgr() {

    }

    public static UsersLogInDataConnMgr getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UsersLogInDataConnMgr();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void setDBType(DBType dbType) {
        this.dbType = dbType;
    }

    private boolean openConnection() {
        try {

            switch (dbType) {

                case MYSQL:
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(M_CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

                    Log.i(TAG, "\nopenConnection() - conn == " + conn + " Return value is TRUE");

                    return true;

                default:
                    Log.i(TAG, "\nopenConnection() - Return value is FALSE");
                    return false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "\nopenConnection() - Connection faliure: - " + e);

            return false;
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (conn == null) {
            if (openConnection()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "\nUsersLogInDataConnMgr - CONNECTION OPENED");
                return conn;
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "\nUsersLogInDataConnMgr - CONNECTION FAILED TO OPEN");
                return null;
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void close() {
        Log.i(TAG, "\nUsersLogInDataConnMgr - CLOSING CONNECTION");
        try {
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "\nUsersLogInDataConnMgr - CONNECTION NOT CLOSED");          
        }
    }

}
```

Below is my **DBType** class:

```
public enum DBType {
    MYSQL
}
```

Below is my **DBUtil** class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.util.Log;

public class DBUtil {

    private static UsersLogInDataConnMgr instance = null;
    private static final String USERNAME = "uname";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "pwrd";
    private static String TAG = "DBUtil";

    public static Connection getConnection(DBType dbType) throws SQLException {

        switch (dbType) {
            case MYSQL:
                return DriverManager.getConnection(M_CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    public static void processException(SQLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error message: " + e.getMessage());
        Log.e(TAG, "Error code: " + e.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, "SQL state: " + e.getSQLState());
    }

}
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You can't directly access remote database from android.
You should create some webapp that will access your database, and you should communicate with that webapp somehow. For example using REST architecture.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704672/how-to-connect-an-android-app-to-a-remote-database

Comment: yes, he can, but it is not a good idea(in fact it is a very bad idea, and yes, REST solution is much better) ... but still http://bit.ly/14z2mf6

Comment: @Selvin i thought we can't do such things because it is not provided by the framework. Can you give me some link where i can read about such approach? I don't want to implement this, but i am interested how can we achieve this.

Comment: @Anatol: thanks for the comments. I had no idea a remote DB can't be accessed via Android. Is that the reason behind the No suitable driver error I'm getting?

Comment: @Selvin: Any ideas where I could find a work around which I could implement a temporary solution as I'm not familiar with REST

Comment: Sorry ignore my above post. Clearly accessing the remote DB directly is a no go in terms of security.